# Using aspectJweaver while running testNG tests programatically

Tags: testng, maven-surefire-plugin, allure

I am using a java class to generate testNG xml dynamically from an excel file. I am using *allure-cli* to generate allure reports at the end of my test execution.

I am using **maven-surefire-plugin** with this following configuration.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>

                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

I am able to generate allure report with full logs and screenshots that are attached by allure annotations (@step, @attachments, @Story ..) when tests are triggered by maven goals and phases.

However I am not able to get the same report when tests are triggered by the java class ( which generates testNG xml & then runs it). 
The code for generating xml is :-

```
public static  void runTestNGTests(Map<Integer,List<String>> testMap){

         TestNG myTestNG = new TestNG();     
         XmlSuite mySuite = new XmlSuite();
         mySuite.setName(suiteName);        


         List<XmlTest> myTests = new ArrayList<XmlTest>();

         for(Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> map : testMap.entrySet()){


             XmlTest myTest = new XmlTest(mySuite);

             myTest.setName(map.getKey()+".) web Test : "+map.getValue().get(0) + " on "+ map.getValue().get(1));        
             myTest.addParameter("Date", map.getValue().get(0));
             myTest.setXmlClasses(Arrays.asList(new XmlClass("com.bravura.tests."+map.getValue().get(1))));

             myTests.add(myTest);
         }



         mySuite.setTests(myTests);

         List<XmlSuite> mySuites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
         mySuites.add(mySuite);

            myTestNG.setXmlSuites(mySuites);
             myTestNG.run(); 
    }
}
```

Do I have to include *javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar* in my **testNG.xml** to get proper testbody logs in allure report?

Comment: Did u find the solution to make the Annotation work and include into allure reports while running testNg programmatically ? .

Answer (score 0):

```
mySuite.addListener("path.to.your.listener");
```

This solution gets you the report without steps. Can't find a solution for collecting the steps.